# Why does looping over tweepy data seems do delete the data?

Tags: python, loops, twitter, tweepy

I'm using the Twitte API (with Tweepy) to extract a number of tweets via Python.

I'm looping

```
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
               q=((search_term) ),
               since = str(t2)).items(10)
```

After I get the tweets, I run through a loop that puts the data within a dataframe:

[image]

However, when I run the code again, data has seemed to dissapear:

[image]

Is there something I could be doing differently? My purpose is to continue adding columns to the dataframe from the same tweet data, but since the data appears to dissapear after the first loop, I can't get it done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `items` property of class `tweepy.Cursor` is not a list, but an iterator, see [documentation](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/v1_pagination.html#tweepy.Cursor).